# Using ftd2xx.dll in python, what is the approximate time to read and write registers?

Tags: python, fpga, spi

Using ftd2xx.dll in python, what is the approximate time to read and write registers? My application is to access FT2232H via FPGA by SPI, which takes 300+ms to read a register. He's too slow. Do you have any ideas?

note: bitmode is MCU Host Bus Emulation

Reading a register is 60+ms in VB,I expect access speeds like this in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. What libraries are you using for Python and VB? How do you measure the performance(time interval)? Are you considering the library or an object initialization task?